# Problema ao mostrar id na tela inicial ao usar sqlite no android studio

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

eu estou desenvolvendo um app no android studio onde ele mostra o id e o nome de um anime q vem do banco de dados ao fazer o cadastro do anime na tela de cadastro de animes, contudo ao apagar um anime da tabela do banco de dados na tela de edita anime, quando ele retorna a tela inicial que mostra o id e o nome do anime, ele mostra por exemplo, se eu tenho 3 animes cadastrado e eu deleto o 2, o terceiro ele n fica com o id 2, eu to usando um autoincremento ao criar o id na tabela do banco de dados e caso eu apague tudo e começo a criar a lista dos animes, ao finalizar o cadastro ele começa com o id com 1 a mais do ultimo q tava e n do 0, tipo com tudo apagado era pra quando eu adicionasse um novo o id fosse 1 e não por exemplo 7 ou 8, supondo q ao apagar a lista tinha cadastrado 6 ou 7 animes. oq eu quero fazer é o seguinte o funcionamento de adicionar e mostrar o anime e o id está certinho se cadastrar o 1 anime, ele mostra 1 e o nome do anime, cadastro o 2 e mostrar 2 e o nome e assim vai, contudo ao deletar um anime, eu quero q todos os ids fiquem certos tbm e n tipo como se tivesse pulado por exemplo eu fiz 7 animes e apaguei o 2, o 4 e o 6 e ao voltar na tela inicial ficar mostrando os ids 1,3,5,7, quero q apos apagar um anime a lista fique certinho caso eu apague os msm animes q falei ai em cima, que fique 1,2,3,4. Isso é possivel de fazer se sim por favor alguem pode me ajudar, vou está postando os codigos das classes e dos layout aqui em baixo nas respostas.

Comment: Esse é o comportamento padrao do auto_increment , acho que não dar pra mudar, alem de causar erros se mudar pois, o delete e edit, faz as operaçoes na maioria das vezes baseadas no id. Voce no entanto pode criar um atribuito e colocar o valor conforme a posicao dele no seu ArrayList e exibir ele em vez do id.

Comment: e como eu posso fazer isso man, vc consegue me mandar o codigo e onde eu preciso colocar esse codigo atravez dos codigos q eu mandei ai, só novo na programação e n sei mts coisas, fiz isso ai atraves de um curso

Comment: [Dar uma olhada aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186899/v%C3%A1rios-dados-em-um-arrayadapter)

Comment: mas n da pra fazer do jeito q ta ai, pq o meu eu estou usando os dados q vao para o banco de dados e já ai ele usa apenas os valores q estão no campo de texto, talves se eu fizesse como vc falo, tipo eu criei um campo codigo para o usuario digitar e ai ele mostrasse na tela principal esse codigo e o nome do anime, contudo quando vou colocar o id do campo codigo da erro fala q n existe a coluna no banco de dados msm se eu ja tenha criado a coluna e so aceita se for esse id

Answer (score 0):

codigo da mainActivity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BancoDeDados bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(getBaseContext());

    final Cursor cursor = bancoDeDados.obterAnimes();

    String[] nomeCampos = new String[] {"_id", "nome"};

    int[] idViews = new int[] {R.id.labelId, R.id.labelTitulo};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adaptador = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.modelo_lista,cursor,nomeCampos,idViews,0);

    ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaDeAnimes);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditarAnime.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

public void abrirTelaCriarNovoAnime(View v){
    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, CriarAnime.class);
    startActivity(startNewActivity);
}
```

}

codigo da tela criar anime

public class CriarAnime extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_criar_anime);
}

public void voltar (View v){
    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startNewActivity);
}

public void criarAnime (View v){

    BancoDeDados bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(getBaseContext());
    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
    EditText numeroEpisodios = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNumeroEpisodios);
    EditText temporadas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoTemporadas);

    if( TextUtils.isEmpty(nome.getText())){

        nome.setError( "Informe o nome do anime" );

    }if (TextUtils.isEmpty(numeroEpisodios.getText())){
        numeroEpisodios.setError("Informe o número de episódios");
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(temporadas.getText())){
        temporadas.setError("Informe o a quantidade de temporadas");
    }
    else{
        boolean resultado = bancoDeDados.criarAnime(nome.getText().toString(), numeroEpisodios.getText().toString(), temporadas.getText().toString());

        if (resultado) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Anime criado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Infelizmente ocorreu um erro, tente novamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        voltar(v);
    }
}
```

}

codigo da tela edita anime

public class EditarAnime extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edita_anime);

    BancoDeDados bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(getBaseContext());
    final Cursor cursor = bancoDeDados.consultarAnimePeloId(this.getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0));

    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
    EditText numeroEpisodios = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNumeroEpisodios);
    EditText tempordas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoTemporadas);

    nome.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nome")));
    numeroEpisodios.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("numeroEpisodios")));
    tempordas.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("temporadas")));
    
}

public void voltar(View v){
    Intent startNewActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(startNewActivity);
}


public void atualizarAnime(View v){

    BancoDeDados bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(getBaseContext());

    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
    EditText numeroEpisodios = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNumeroEpisodios);
    EditText tempordas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoTemporadas);


    try {
        bancoDeDados.atualizaAnime(this.getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0),nome.getText().toString(), numeroEpisodios.getText().toString(), tempordas.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Anime atualizada com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possível atualizar o anime, tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    voltar(v);
}

public void excluiAnime(View v, SQLiteDatabase db){
    BancoDeDados bancoDeDados = new BancoDeDados(getBaseContext());

    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
    EditText numeroEpisodios = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoNumeroEpisodios);
    EditText tempordas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.campoTemporadas);

    try {

        bancoDeDados.excluiAnime(this.getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0));
        

        Toast.makeText(this, "Anime excluído com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possível excluir o anime, tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    voltar(v);
}
```

}

codigo da classe gerenciar banco

public class GerenciarBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String NOME_BANCO = "bancoDeDados.db";
public static final int VERSAO = 1;

public GerenciarBanco(Context context){
    super(context,NOME_BANCO,null,VERSAO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql="CREATE TABLE animes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome text, numeroEpisodios text, temporadas text)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS animes");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

codigo da classe banco de dados

public class BancoDeDados {

```
public SQLiteDatabase banco;
public GerenciarBanco gerenciarBanco;

public BancoDeDados(Context context){
    gerenciarBanco = new GerenciarBanco(context);
}

public boolean criarAnime(String nome, String numeroEpisodios, String temporadas){

    banco = gerenciarBanco.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("nome", nome);
    valores.put("numeroEpisodios", numeroEpisodios);
    valores.put("temporadas", temporadas);

    long resultado = banco.insert("animes", null, valores);
    banco.close();

    return resultado > 0;
}

public Cursor obterAnimes(){

    String[] campos = {"_id", "nome"};
    SQLiteDatabase db = gerenciarBanco.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("animes", campos, null,null,null,null, "_id ASC");

    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    db.close();
    return cursor;
}

public void atualizaAnime(int id, String nome, String numeroEpisodios, String temporadas){
    SQLiteDatabase db = gerenciarBanco.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = "_id = " + id;

    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("nome", nome);
    valores.put("numeroEpisodios", numeroEpisodios);
    valores.put("temporadas", temporadas);

    db.update("animes", valores, where, null);
    db.close();
}

public void excluiAnime(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = gerenciarBanco.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = "_id = " + id;
    db.delete("animes", where, null);
    db.close();
}

public Cursor consultarAnimePeloId(int notaId){
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] campos = {"_id", "nome", "numeroEpisodios", "temporadas"};
    String where = "_id = " + notaId;
    SQLiteDatabase db = gerenciarBanco.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query("animes", campos, where, null,null,null,null,null);

    if (cursor !=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

}

Vou enviar os codigos em xml dos layout.

Answer (score 0):

xml da tela mainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ANIMES"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"></TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaDeAnimes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.92"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"></ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaoCriarAnime"
    android:text="Adicionar Anime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:onClick="abrirTelaCriarNovoAnime"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

xml da tela criar anime

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.CriarAnime">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Criar Novo Anime"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campoNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Nome do Anime:"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campoNumeroEpisodios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Número de Episódios:"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campoTemporadas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Quantidade de Temporadas:"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoCriar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Criar"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:onClick="criarAnime"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoCancelar"
            android:text="Cancelar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="voltar"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

xml da tela edita anime

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="64dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="64dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.EditarAnime">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Atualizar Anime"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campoNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Nome do Anime:"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campoNumeroEpisodios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Número de Episódios:"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/campoTemporadas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:hint="Quantidade de Temporadas:"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoGravar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="atualizarAnime"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Gravar"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/botaoExcluir"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="excluiAnime"
            android:text="Excluir"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

xml do modelo lista

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelId"
    android:text="ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelTitulo"
    android:text="TITULO"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

se alguem poder me ajudar a resolver essa questao dos ids eu agradeço dmssss